# Reading from a data sheet using Java or C#

Tags: java, c#, excel, stream

I would consider myself an amateur programmer.  I've taken Java classes and i'm in the process of self-teaching myself C#.
When it comes to Reading Data (say for example an Excel file)  I've noticed a trend, It always begins with Open...ImportData/ManipulateData/ExportData....Export

**My question:**
Is there some other way to read data other than the "OpenStream" "CloseStream" that I know of already?
I know that there are a ton of different languages out there, but maybe a built in function that I don't know of already for Java or C#?

Comment: This is way too vague. I'm not sure which "general pattern" you are referring to (export data? what do you mean?). And of course, there are types of data storage, like database or NOSQL etc. which are not manipulated serially. In short, your question is not really answerable.

Comment: I apologize,I'm still getting the hang of stack overflow.  The way I was taught in Java was essentially, OpenStream, ReadFromFile, Close Stream.

Now I'm trying to learn C# and I thought I had seen a similar "Framework " for reading from a file, and I was curious if this was kind of the way most of code was written for reading from a file

Comment: If you want to manipulate data from an Excel file, it won't be just open/import/manipulate/export/close. You will need specific libraries for Java or C# that can manipulate Excel files. The Excel file format is complex. It is not a simple text file format.

Answer (score 1):

I/O operations are essentially streaming operations. Your main logic stored and executed inside the memory. After that you can dump the result, temporary calculations or the application state down to the disk. The traditional way to achive this is using streams (filestream, networkstream...) because the data is layed down one after another. Usually these streams are not random access streams, thats why there is easy to work with them.

In C# if you dont want to open or close disposable objects manually you can use the using statement.